# Xubutu 20.04 Big problem with nvidia gt 630

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, graphics, xubuntu

I recently changed my os (because i had to) from older version of Xubuntu (18) to new one. but there is a problem with my graphic card that took long a days (and suspended my job :(( cause my job is with my pc).

### Problem definition:

When i installed new LTS Xubuntu the default graphic driver (aka nouveau) was installed on it. at first it was working so good but in continue i had many times encountering ui or whole pc crash (both happened) and sometimes erratic mouse move (showing a problem exists in the system).

### Tried solutions:

- Changing to recommended proprietary driver: nvidia-340: this version is not supported in current kernel (5.11). the driver installation ended up with error in running post installation scripts and rolling back to another driver version.
- Changing to recommended proprietary driver: nvidia-driver-390: this version is being installed and working correctly sometime. even nvidia settings application (sometimes) is being showed so good. but after rebooting the system the driver didn't work and nivida settings page won't load (just empty page).
  currently i solved the problem partially by following steps:

  - removing nvidia drivers: `sudo apt purge nvidia*` `sudo apt autoremove`
  - blocking nouveau driver by following steps described [there](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-blacklist-nouveau-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux).
  - adding the `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` to /etc/grub/default and running `sudo update-grub`
  - selecting nvidia-driver-390 from other drivers tab (in software and updated). sometimes with running `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390`
    atfer doing this items something strange did happen. display resolution is perfect but nvidia settings just shows an empty page. but the strange thing is about my mouse device (i'm using logitech k235 wireless mouse and keyboard); my mouse is moving with delay. mouse clicks and keyboard are ok and mouse just has delay (not erratic move or something else just latency exists). if this problem (mouse delay) could be solved i think it should be ok and i can back to my job.
    Also it should be notable that this one is which i'm currently using (now i'm on this solution).
    another thing may be relate to this solution is kernel `CONFIG_DRM` option related to sett `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` in grub as mentioned [there](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/396.51/README/kms.html). should i check or enable this option???
- Installing official package from nvidia site. this one neither worked and ended with errors (as i remember that needs kernel 5.4).
- I also tried other existing nvidia driver versions: 331, 384, 418, 430, 440. The 4x drivers didn't work as system crashed completely after seconds after login page loaded. two other versions automatically showed as higher recommended version  (340 for 318 and 390 for 384) in other drivers page and also didn't work.

sorry if my tail became long. i tried whatever i could and now i think i need help.
Thanks for incoming helps.

Comment: The GA kernel for 20.04 is 5.4, so why haven't you installed/tried out using the GA kernel stack?  (LTS releases come with two kernel stack choices - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)   Xubuntu's latest release is 21.10 which doesn't have that option (nor did the prior two releases, but LTS release do).  Xubuntu is a desktop system, so has no 18 release (Ubuntu has used the *year* for *snap* only products since 2016 which are a appliance/server product)

Comment: @guiverc thank you so much. do you recommend to install kernel 5.4? how can i do that?

Comment: The link I provided in the first post contains a "*To downgrade from HWE/OEM to GA kernel:*" section which tells you how.  If you're on very new equipment you generally want the newest *drivers* (which are kernel modules; thus tied to the kernel in use so later kernels give newer hardware often better choices) but otherwise GA is the more *stable* (why it's default for server installs!).  There are a few features that require the HWE kernel stack but you can have both installed selecting which you use at boot time.

Comment: @guiverci installed kernel 5.4 as second option but it didn't work.

Comment: @guiverc  Unfortunately loging in with kernel 5.4 didn't make difference. :(

Comment: Geforce 630 is supported by 470.74 . So you have to use GA kernel with this driver version. Uninstall HWE and proceed.

Comment: @N0rbert I tried this solution. i even removed other versions of kernel but it didn't work. finally i installed Xubuntu 18.04 and everything seems OK!